# RuntimeError: unexpected EOF, expected 3302200 more bytes. The file might be corrupted

Tags: pytorch, pre-trained-model, torchvision

I am trying to implement pretrained model of following repository. I need your assistance to rectify the error.

RuntimeError: unexpected EOF, expected 3302200 more bytes. The file might be corrupted.

I tried to implement pretrained model of CANNet present on following repo using google Collab and followed all steps of (**Prerequisites, cloning, Data Preparation, and Testing**)

```
https://github.com/gjy3035/NWPU-Crowd-Sample-Code.git
```

The detailed error is given below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 118, in
main()
File "test.py", line 46, in main
test(lines, model_path)
File "test.py", line 55, in test
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 593, in load
return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 779, in _legacy_load
deserialized_objects[key]._set_from_file(f, offset, f_should_read_directly)
RuntimeError: unexpected EOF, expected 3302200 more bytes. The file might be corrupted.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this github link: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1491
It proposes one should use the `force_download` arg. This is equivalent to `force_reload` assuming you're using `torch.load.hub` to load the pretrained model. The other option proposed is applicable to windows users is to delete the downloaded model and download it again.

I have the same issue but --setting `force_reload=True` hasn't cleared it for me, I'm thinking I have space problems, but I think it's worth a shot on your end.

Comment: I solved it by deleting the corrupted download.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same same problem while I was evaluating my trained model on google collab. I found that the model was taking a lot of time to get fully uploaded to the machine. I was testing with the incompletely uploaded model. when I ensured that the model has been fully uploaded and then I ran, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with 'openpose.pth' in folder extensions/controlnet/model, go to stable-diffusion-webui/models/openpose, check your 'body_pose_model.pth' and 'hand_pose_model.pth', maybe they are corrupted, delete them and then reload.